Is there any Catalyst Node SDK method to get the file details from the Catalyst Filestore
There is no Catalyst SDK method to get the file details from the Catalyst Filestore.
I want to get the file details from the Catalyst Filestore. How can I get the single file details from the Catalyst Filestore? Is there any Catalyst SDK method to get the single file details?

You can use getFileDetails() Node SDK method to get a single file details from the Catalyst Filestore. However, this method is not included in their documentation.
`let catalystApp = catalyst.initialize(req);
let filestore = catalystApp.filestore();
let folder = filestore.folder(FolderID);
let getfilePromise = folder.getFileDetails(FileID); // //This method returns a response as a promise
//The promise returned here will be resolved to a JSON object.
getfilePromise.then((resp) => {
console.log(resp);

res.status(200).send(resp);

});`
